# How to hide URLin JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an problem here.
In jquery ajax when we define url here its been expsed to outside world

there is chance it would be missued by others how can we overcome this so that URL is encoded ?
ar actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetMovieslist", "Getjson")';

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Actionname attribute used here.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGetMovies2").click(function () {
            //var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetMovieslist", "Getjson")';
            var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetMovieslist", "Getjson")';
            $.getJSON(actionUrl, displayData2);
        });
    });

    function displayData2(response) {
        if (response != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $("#movieList2").append("<li>" + response[i].Title + " " + response[i].Genre + " " + response[i].Year + "</li>")
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So is there any way we can oversome this issue

Comment: You can't. You should add validation on the server-side to prevent misuse. If you need to be logged in, for example, you could add a user-specific token as a parameter to prevent non-users from having results returned.

Comment: It's client code, it's not possible to hide it from the client. Otherwise, the browser wouldn't know how to submit your AJAX query.

Comment: Use `tinyUrl` and provide into the Urlmapping table.

Comment: @Amit That would still provide a URL that could be misused by others.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is sent across from the client can be seen by the client. In your case, if the client opens up the 'network' panel in Chrome, they can see the endpoint they're hitting.

If you don't want that, you have one foolproof option:

Don't serve that content from an AJAX call; serve it from the server.

You can always take in a `token` parameter with your AJAX method and log that token (and check it for abuse), but you can't outright stop an end user from hitting that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what George said.
Additionally, if you're worried about csrf attacks,
XMLHttpRequest is subject to the browser's same-origin policy: for security reasons, requests will only succeed if they are made from the same origin.